# Django tutorial with version 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I am using Django 1.6.5. It seems that the version used in the tutorial is quite different from mine. For example, there are no `migrate`-related commands available in my `manage.py`. I got around this problem momentarily by downloading the South library and typing `syncdb` instead of `migrate`. But now the tutorial wants me to type:

```
python manage.py makemigration polls
```

which neither South nor the original Django has. Am I doomed? Do I have to install a much later version of Django? This seems strange to me because doing so is quite nettlesome. Installing 1.6 is by far the easiest to install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the `dev` part in the URL with `1.6`, so it becomes:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

You can find links to the different versions of documentation on the menu in the bottom, right hand side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There are different tutorials for all the different versions. The one you're using is for the most recent version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/ would be tutorial for Django 1.6